# how to pass data and develop applications

Tags: jquery

Trying to sort out some general things considering usage of js and jquery particularly.
Was reading ~million of answers through stackoverflow without clean understanding how to pass data to another function and how do we build applications.

I got pretty usual schema:

```
$(document).ready(function){

   $('.classname').click(function() { 
      var varone = $(this).attr('name');
   });

   $('.class2name').click(function(){
      var vartwo = $(this).height();
   });

});
```

Then i go out from (document).ready and want to do some handling like

```
    function dosmth() {
       var freaksum = varone + vartwo;
    }
```

How do i do that? I want to pass objects, not make globals.

What are the practices to handle such things developing large applications?
I want to have some function which is making lot of operations with lot of variables from other functions. How do i get all these objects in my operational function? 
What if i have to use these variables not inside a single function, but in several different functions, like

```
function dosmth() {
   var freaksum = varone + vartwo;
}

function dosmthelse() {
   var freakmult = varone * vartwo;
}
```

etc etc

Sorry for a long one, thank you.

Comment: One way to achieve this is through a self-contained plugin. Another, depending on your situation, is to use .data('something',someValue); on an element you're manipulating or referencing. That can be namespaced, so to speak, as well. If you're working in jQuery, you can define your variables within $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); before your other declarations. You may always want to do things like function dosmth(){ var sum=$obj.data('varone')+$obj.data('vartwo');} or a plugin to encapsulate the logic $.fn.yourPlugin = function(){}, see plugin building for some ideas on this path.

Comment: Cool, thank you MyStream. I guess best way to have a clean code is to make a plugin for that purposes. I can move all the logical part there, and keep getting the data from the page by usual methods.
Even didn't think about such opportunity before... Guess if we have lot of different data to handle, we just have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example, your two functions `dosmth` and `dosmthelse` do not have any access to the variables `varone` and `vartwo` because they do not exist in the same scope. <strike>The only</strike>One way around this is to make those variables exist in a scope that is available to both the click events and the functions.

The easiest way is to simply make them global.

```
var varone, vartwo;

$(document).ready(function){
   $('.classname').click(function() { 
      varone = $(this).attr('name');
   });

   $('.class2name').click(function(){
      vartwo = $(this).height();
   });
});
function dosmth() {
   var freaksum = varone + vartwo;
}

function dosmthelse() {
   var freakmult = varone * vartwo;
}
```

However it is usually better to not use the global scope, so we can instead do it this way:

```
(function($){
    var varone, vartwo;
    $(document).ready(function){
       $('.classname').click(function() { 
          varone = $(this).attr('name');
       });

       $('.class2name').click(function(){
          vartwo = $(this).height();
       });
    });
    function dosmth() {
       var freaksum = varone + vartwo;
    }

    function dosmthelse() {
       var freakmult = varone * vartwo;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Now you don't have any global variables and they are still accessible in both places.

You could also (depending on your situation) store those values somewhere else, such as on an element.

Without more information on the real-world situation you are trying to solve, that's about as far as I can go.

Comment: Yeah, globals are not what i want to use.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Kevin. My question is more about the best practices how to develop complex applications (or, say, doing complicated things with the data). Second example looks cool, but i'm not sure - is it ok from the point of memory/performance? I mean, we got everything inside one large function and not too straight hands, is everything going to hang? At the same time if things are separated, problems could start just when the poor code is executed, no?

Comment: I don't think you would have any issues with the second example as far as memory/performance, but like you said, it's for a very simple example. A more complex application would be better handled using a custom-built framework that stores the information you need in a place where you can access it.